# Subaddress (emails with plus) not working when email goes via Microsoft Exchange Frontend Transport

Tags: email-server, exchange-hybrid

I'm trying to send an email to recipient user+test@example.com via the local server with Frontend Transport setup on it (hybrid Microsoft Exchange Setup).

If the email domain belongs to the server, then error '550 5.1.10 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipientNotFound; Recipient not found by SMTP address lookup' appearing, otherwise it works well (e.g. if the email is usre+test@gmail.com - it will work).

If I'm sending an email to user+test@example.com directly (not via Frontend Transport, such as from GMail for example), then it works.

Is it possible to adjust settings on Frontend Transport to support '+' emails?
Or to not check recipients towards local users if an email has been sent from a specific IP address.

PS:

- [RFC5233 is dated January 2008](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233)
- [Microsoft added support for plus addresses as of May 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/plus-addressing-in-exchange-online)

Comment: Please provide your transport configuration by editing your post using `Get-TransportConfig | Format-List` and check the logs, the logs might provide more insight. Di other Gmail work because Gmail is very strict on smtp tls. And do also have also rollup updates installed which provide the support

Answer (score -2):

Based on my research, the error message ‘550 5.1.10 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipientNotFound; Recipient not found by SMTP address lookup’ indicates that the recipient email address is not valid or does not exist.

Regarding the issue with the ‘+’ sign in the email address, it seems that the ‘+’ sign is not a valid character for email addresses according to the SMTP protocol. However, some email providers such as Gmail allow the use of the ‘+’ sign in email addresses.

As for adjusting settings on Frontend Transport to support ‘+’ emails, I could not find any official documentation from Microsoft that confirms this is possible. However, there are some third-party tools that claim to enable this functionality.

Regarding the second part of your question, it is possible to configure Exchange to bypass recipient filtering for specific IP addresses. You can create a new Receive connector and specify the IP addresses that should bypass recipient filtering

Comment: `+` is perfectly valid for mail addresses.